# AVX2 narrowing conversion, from uint16_t to uint8_t

Tags: simd, avx, avx2, narrowing

I'd like to narrow a 2d array from 16 to 8 bits, using AVX2.  The C++ code that works is as follows:

```c++
  auto * s = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(i_frame.Y);
  auto * d = narrowed.data();

  for (auto y = 0; y < i_frame.Height; y++, s += i_frame.Pitch_Luma / 2, d += o_frame.Width)
  {
      for (auto x = 0; x < i_frame.Width; x++)
      {
          d[x] = static_cast<uint8_t>(s[x]);
      }
  }
```

Then I thought perhaps it would be more efficient to use AVX2 (all our systems have AVX2 support):

```c++
 auto * s = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(i_frame.Y);
 auto * d = narrowed.data();

 for (auto y = 0; y < i_frame.Height; ++y, s += i_frame.Pitch_Luma / 2, d += o_frame.Width)
 {
     for (auto x = 0; x < i_frame.Width; x += 16)
     {
         auto src = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i *>(s + x));            
         auto v = _mm256_packus_epi16(src, _mm256_setzero_si256());

         v = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));

         _mm_store_si128(reinterpret_cast<__m128i *>(d + x), _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 0));
     }
 }
```

Question is whether my AVX2 conversion code is optimal and/or the correct way to do this.  I may be missing an AVX2 command that makes this very easy.  At least I was with the widening conversion.

Comment: What do you want to happen for numbers outside the range 0..255? Or will they not occur so it doesn't matter?

Comment: BTW your `auto` loop variables will be `int` (I think?) which may not be what you wanted

Comment: The numbers outside the range don't occur.  It's 0 to 255.  The source is 16 bits and I don't control that.

Comment: Does your source actually come from memory or a previous operation? If possible, you should combine whatever calculated the 16bit result directly with the down-conversion instead of first storing the 16bit values. (Of course, sometimes this is not possible ...)

Comment: Note that scalar defer of `s = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(...)` is a strict-aliasing violation if the underlying data isn't `[u]int16_t` aka `[unsigned] short`  (i.e. if you're accessed it with any type other than SIMD or `[unsigned] char*`).  SIMD load intrinsics like `_mm256_load_si256` are strict-aliasing safe.  Code like this could make sense if the pointer is `void*`, or an `unsigned char*` to dynamically-allocated memory so there is no declared data type, only accesses.

Comment: Yes the pointers are void *.  I am not in control of hardware producing the values and I must interpret the memory block according to a format flag.  It may be uint16_t, uint8_t luma or some other format like UYVY or YUY2.  This is part of the function that does the uint8_t conversion.  It will become the luma plane of an NV12 semi-planar surface.  The pointers are guaranteed to be aligned and are allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vpackuswb` and `vpermq` are fine for this, but you can arrange things so you get double the work done with those same instructions:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x += 32)
{
    auto src1 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i *>(s + x));
    auto src2 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<const __m256i *>(s + x + 16));
   // sources are known to be in the 0..255 range so no saturation happens
    auto v = _mm256_packus_epi16(src1, src2);

    v = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));

    _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i *>(d + x), v);
}
```

This may not be quite a drop-in replacement since the unroll factor changed, and so this may require additional care near the edge of the image. You may also need an unaligned store, if the destination was only 16-aligned (or increase the alignment if possible).

---

`vpackuswb` interprets the source data as signed `int16_t`, and saturates values outside the 0..255 range as it packs down to `uint8_t`.  For inputs that never have the highest bit set (e.g. 10-bit or 12-bit unsigned in uint16_t elements), values above 255 with saturate to 255.  But if the high bit is set, like full-range `uint16_t` input, it's treated as signed-negative and saturated to 0.  (`packs` to do signed saturation to the `-128 .. +127` isn't much more helpful when you want unsigned output.)

To truncate the bit-patterns (modulo instead of saturate), you'd want `_mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x00FF))` on both inputs separately *before* packing.

Or if you want to keep the most-significant 8 bits of each `uint16_t`, you could shift them like `_mm256_srli_epi16(src1, 2)` to discard the low 2 bits of 10-bit data and put the rest at the bottom, ready for a saturating pack.

Shift Right Logical shifts in zeros, so this is usable on full-range `uint16_t`.  With the shift-count being 8 for full-range u16, it's tempting to want to use whole-byte tricks like an unaligned load so the bytes we want are already in the bottom of each word element, but then we'd have to `and`.  That could cost fewer uops (e.g. with a memory source operand for `vpand` but not shift-immediate until AVX-512), and non-shuffle uops that can run on more ports, but every other load will be a cache-line split which may be a worse bottleneck than the front-end.

Comment: Thanks Harold.  This seems to work great.  I know the data is 0...255 and also that the data is 32 byte aligned, and the width is a multiple of 32 (1280, 1920, 3840, etc.) so I don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @Robinson: I added those comments for the benefit of future readers who might have a problem with the same title but different details, e.g. 10-bit or 12-bit pixel data or 16-bit audio data.

Answer (score 3):

If you have AVX-512 available, you might still just use the same `_mm256_packus_epi16` / `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` strategy as in harold's answer if your data is in the 0..255 range, or if i16 to u8 saturation works for your use-case.  On Intel CPUs, it will produce one vector of results every other clock cycle, from 2 vectors of inputs, if it doesn't bottleneck on cache bandwidth.  (Both shuffles run on port 5 only, even for the YMM version.)

Optimizing for throughput per uop makes the most sense if you're doing this on the fly with some other work in the same pass over the data, or as you generate it; or if you can cache-block this so inputs and output are hot in L1d cache.  (An average per cycle of loading 32 bytes and storing 16 probably does saturate L2 bandwidth on Intel, but shifting or ANDing would slow it a bit with front-end issue or back-end port bottlenecks.)  If you're doing something nasty like bottlenecking on DRAM bandwidth, the best you can do is let the other logical core have more execution resources by doing this efficiently.  And let out-of-order exec see farther for better HW prefetch.

You might use 512-bit vectors so that's 64 bytes of results per 2 cycles = 32 bytes per cycle on Intel.  That would need a vector constant for `_mm512_permutexvar_epi64` because `vpermq zmm, zmm, imm8` reuses the imm8 to do the same independent 256-bit shuffle in the two halves of the vector, because an 8-bit immediate only has room for four 2-bit fields.

On Zen 4, pack/permute gives 32 result bytes per cycle with either 32-byte or 64-byte vectors.  (The YMM versions of the shuffles have 0.5c throughput on Zen 4, and L1d load/store throughput is 64 bytes loaded + 32 stored.  512-bit vectors occupy the execution unit for 2 cycles but are single-uop even for lane-crossing shuffles.)

**Where AVX-512 shines is when you want to ignore the upper byte of your `uint16_t` input (truncating bit-patterns i.e. taking modulo), or do actual unsigned saturation that treats the *input* as unsigned as well as the output range.**  Or on Zen 4, for a single-uop lane-crossing 2-input shuffle with byte granularity.  (It's 3 uops on Intel so not better than pack/permute if the upper bytes are zero so that's equivalent. :/)

---

If AVX-512VBMI is available, `vperm2tb` (`_mm256_permutex2var_epi8`) can pick bytes from 2 source vectors without restrictions, getting the whole job done in one instruction.  It costs 3 uops on Ice Lake and Alder Lake (including two port-5-only).  Only a single uop on Zen 4, though.  https://uops.info/.

With AVX-512 but not AVX-512VBMI, or if you don't want to load a 64-byte shuffle constant, you might prefer `_mm256_cvtepi16_epi8` ([`vpmovwb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovwb:vpmovswb:vpmovuswb)) which produces a `__m128i` from one `__m256i` with truncation ignoring the high byte, but unfortunately narrowing so you need twice as many stores as with 2x and / pack / permute or with `vperm2b`.

Or for unsigned-to-unsigned saturation there's `_mm256_cvtusepi16_epi8` (`vpmovuswb`) which unlike pack instructions treats the *input* as `uint16_t`, saturating into the output 0..255 range of the uint8_t output elements.  (Or the `__m512i` to `__m256i` versions if you want to use 512-bit vectors.)

But unfortunately, Intel CPUs (Ice Lake and Sapphire Rapids/Alder Lake at least) implement both of these narrowing conversions as 2 uops.  For a YMM source, p15 + p5, or 2p5 for a ZMM source since the port-1 vector ALU is shut down when there are 512-bit uops in flight, so at best you can produce 16 bytes of results per clock cycle this way, vs. 32 per clock with `vpermt2b zmm` (producing 64 bytes every other cycle).

`vpmovqd` is 1 uop on Intel, but all the other AVX-512 narrowing moves are 2 uops, involving byte or word elements or any saturation.  Intel CPUs since Ice Lake can sustain 1/clock 64-byte store to L1d or 2/clock 256-bit stores to the same cache line which coalesce as they commit (so twice as many 256-bit stores isn't terrible, and is better if your data isn't 64-byte aligned).   Bursts of 64-byte stores can enter the store buffer at 2/clock, but commit to L1d is 1/clock.  But even Alder Lake can "only" load 2x 512-bit per clock, so narrowing

Zen 4 does `vpmov[us]wb` in one uop (with 1c throughput cost for ZMM vs. 0.5c for YMM/XMM, and lower latency than `vpermt2b` but same ports).  So 1/clock shuffle would limit this to 1 source vector per cycle on Zen 4 with this strategy (32 bytes of results per cycle), vs. 2 source vectors per clock for `vpermt2b` producing 64 bytes/cycle of results.  If you're doing computations on the results, having them in one 512-bit vector is generally better, and so is 1 uop per 2 source vectors.  But if you're just loading and storing the results back to memory, you're limited to L1d cache bandwidth 64 bytes loaded (2x 256 or 1x 512) and 32 bytes stores (   But that requires loading a vector constant, and

If your data does work with pack / permute, that might still be the best strategy even with with 512-bit vectors.  (Except on Zen 4 although it's not bad there.)

---

#### https://uops.info/ data on the relevant instructions

Alder Lake P-cores are Golden Cove, same as the cores in Sapphire Rapids, so uops.info's Alder Lake test data applies to SPR, from early Alder Lake systems where it was possible to enable AVX-512 when there were no E-cores.

Unless otherwise noted, each execution unit can accept a new uop every cycle, except on Zen 4 with 512-bit uops which occupy a port for 2 cycles.  (So 1 uop for either of ports FP1 or FP2 (aka FP12) give 0.5c throughput for 128 and 256-bit, 1c for 512-bit.  uops.info confirms those throughput numbers;  I didn't make separate table columns for them since the instructions we're interested in don't have back-end bottlenecks other than ports so the back-end cost is fully captured by the uops.  (Except for stores: commit from the store buffer to L1d cache is only 1/clock on Intel for 64-byte stores, vs. 2/clock for 256-bit and narrower if it can coalesce two stores to the same cache line in Ice Lake and later. Ice Lake and later can *execute* 2x 512-bit stores per clock, but will soon bottleneck on the store buffer being full.)

Intel CPUs shut down the vector ALUs on port 1 when any 512-bit uops are in flight (but not the integer ALUs on port 1: those include the `imul` and `popcnt` units and every integer uop with > 1 cycle of latency).  So for example a `p015` uop becomes a `p05` for the ZMM version of `vpermt2b`, or if using 512-bit uops in code surrounding `vptermt2b ymm`.  (Hrm, does the first 512-bit uop have to wait for existing port-1 vector uops to drain from the scheduler or something?  Otherwise how does it avoid sending a uop to port 0 while a uop for port 1 is expecting to use the high half of the port 0 execution unit via port 1?)

| ports and/or recip tput by uarch | Cascade Lake | Ice Lake | Alder Lake / SPR | Zen 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `vpackuswb` | 1 p5 [fused load] | 1 p5 [fused load] | 1 p5 [fused load] | 1 FP12 |
| `vpermq` imm8 or vec control | 1 p5 | 1 p5 | 1 p5 | 1 FP12 |
| `vpermt2b` `..._permutex2var_epi8` | not supported | 1p015+2p5 | 1p015+2p5 | 1 FP12 |
| `vpand` / `vpandd` | p015 [fused load] | p015 [fused load] | p015 [fused load] | 1 FP0123 (0.25c ymm / 0.5c zmm) |
| `vpsrlw v,v/m,imm8` | p01 [no fusion] | p01 [no fusion] | p01 [no fusion] | 1 FP23 |
| `vpmovwb` `..._cvtepi16_epi8` | 2p5 | p15+p5 | p15+p5 | 1 FP12 |
| `vpmovuswb` `..._cvtusepi16_epi8` | same as above | " | " | " |
| loads/stores |  |  |  |  |
| `_mm256_load_si256` | 0.5c | 0.5c | 0.333c | 0.5c |
| `_mm256_store_si256` | 1c (store-addr can compete w. loads) | 0.5c burst / 1c sustained | 0.5c burst / 1c sustained | 1c despite 2 ports |
| `_mm512_load_si512` | 0.5c | 0.5c | 0.5c despite 3 ports | 1c |
| `_mm512_store_si512` | 1c (store-addr can compete w. loads) | 0.5c burst / 1c sustained | 0.5c burst / 1c sustained | 2c despite 2 ports |

(load/store intrinsics can optimize away depending on how they're used, e.g. on the same location twice.  I'm using them as shorthand for the corresponding uops, either as a memory source operand or `vmovdqa` or `vmovdqa32`, or even `vmovdqu` with an address that happens not to cross a cache line, etc.  This is of course assuming L1d cache hits.)

`[fused load]` means that if there's a memory source operand, it can micro-fuse so they only take one slot in the front-end and ReOrder Buffer (ROB), [unless an indexed addressing mode makes Intel CPUs unlaminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) which is a frequent problem with compilers.  I think AMD CPUs can always keep memory source operands fused even with indexed addressing modes; uops.info still reports 1 total uop for these instructions with a memory source.

`vpermq`'s memory source operand is the shuffle control, not data, so I didn't count it.  On Intel, instruction that are more than 1 uop on their own generally can't micro-fuse a load; that's the case for `vpermt2b` (3, or 4 with a memory source) vs. `vpermt2d` (1, or 1-micro-fused).

`vpmovwb` can't take a memory source, but it can take a memory *destination*.   Narrowing instructions like AVX512F `vpmovdb [rdi]{k1}, zmm0` originally existed as a way for [Xeon Phi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon_Phi) to do byte-masked and word-masked stores without AVX512VL or AVX512BW.   Even single-uop `vpmovqd` can't micro-fuse the store with the ALU, but all forms let the store-address and store-data uops micro-fuse with each other so you save on code-size vs. a separate store.  (But one 3-uop `vpmovwb [rdi], zmm0` instruction could be worse for packing into the uop cache than a 2 + 1 since all 3 uops have to be in the same 6-uop line.)  With intrinsics, it's up to the compiler to decide whether to fold `_mm_storeu_si128` into a memory destination for a `vpmovwb` when storing the result of a `_mm256_cvtepi16_epi8`.

Note that `vpsrlw` on Zen 4 competes with shuffles for port FP2, so AVX2 with 2 shifts / 2 shuffles could only run 3 of the 4 back-end vector ALU uops per clock. `vpand` wouldn't have this problem; it could schedule to the two ports shuffles can't run on.  (We'd also bottleneck on the front end with the 2 loads + 1 store making a total of 7 uops; The AVX1/2 versions are just `vpsrlw v,v,imm8`.  Only the AVX-512 version of `vpsrlw v,v/m, imm8` allows a memory source which would get us down to 5 uops on Zen where it fused unlike Intel.  Plus there's loop overhead modulo how much we unroll.  AVX2 `vpand ymm,ymm,ymm/m256` doesn't have this problem, and can micro-fuse even on Intel if you avoid indexed addressing modes.)  Either way this is only a bottleneck if data is hot in L1d cache.

On Intel, vector shifts are `p01` (or `p0` for the ZMM version), vs. the shuffles we're interested in being port 5 only.  So port 5 limits use to 2 cycles per result whether we need shift or AND; 7 front-end uops per 2 cycles if we need to shift is close to SKX / Cascade Lake's limit of 4/clock, but Ice Lake can handle a couple uops of loop overhead.  (And with shifts not micro-fusing anyway on Intel, but can on AMD, we can use indexed addressing modes, scaling by 2 in the loads and by 1 in the store.  With `vpand`, there is a benefit to pointer increments on Intel if we unroll, though.)

We don't really get a choice between shift and AND; if your input bit-layout is super flexible, choose to put the significant bits at the bottom, zero-extended, so you can use `vpackuswb` without any shift or AND.

If the shift count is `8`, you can use `vpermt2b` with a control vector that grabs the upper bytes of each u16 instead of the lower.

I omitted a Gracemont column for Alder Lake E-cores: we don't have a choice there because it doesn't support AVX10 (for 256-bit-only AVX-512 new instructions.)